# How to reduce multiple tables with different data into a master table (with at least one association)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, database

Lets say that I have have 5 tables, all residing in different sheets.

The tables all contain at least one dimension that can be associated with any other table.

Some of the tables will share multiple, but not all, dimensions. Between different tables they may or may not be the same dimensions or the same number of dimensions.

I want to condense the number of dimensions I need into the minimum number of dimensions for a master table. Is there a way to put these 5 tables into a single sheet as a master table that contains all the data?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried Excel's various lookup functions? If your version of Excel supports it, start with `=XLOOKUP()`: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929

Comment: Welcome to Super User,, please [edit] your post & share some sample data with us ,, also be clear & loud all about your expectations,,, what U are trying to extract from 5 Tables ,,, are any value/column common between them ?

Comment: Could you provide a simple sample about this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Create a query separately on each table by using Data>Get & Transform Data>From Table/Range

Then use Data>Get & Transform Data>Get Data>Combine Queries>Merge to join one query to another.

Do this for the first two queries, then join the third to the first two, then the fourth, and so on.

At each merge operation, a column will be added to the first table in the join with the word Table in every row. You must click the double-headed arrow in the top of that column in the Power Query Editor to expand the columns from the second query in the join. As you expand, you can select to add specific columns from the second query. This is how you can ensure you don't have the same column twice.

For example:

[image]

You see the column with the word Table in every row:

[image]

When expanding the columns by clicking the double-arrow, un-select the join column:

[image]

This has now merged the two tables:

[image]

You can repeat the process as many times as you like using previous results.

After each merge, click "Close & Load To" and select "Only create connection" to avoid creating lots of unnecessary sheets in your file. It will only create the query, which can then be used in further merges.

You can read more about the Merge operation [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/merge-queries-power-query-fd157620-5470-4c0f-b132-7ca2616d17f9).